# Синтаксис ассемблерных вставок в C++

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где почитать документацию по ассемблерным вставкам в код на C++. Например  что означает выражение в операнде:
`jnz $+11`. Я понимаю, что это адрес метки, но что здесь означает знак доллара?

Answer (score 3):

По вашему конкретному вопросу - `$` - это предопределенная метка, указывающая текущий адрес. Так что

```
jmp $
```

это просто бесконечный цикл :) У вас - переход в точку, определяемую смещением от текущего адреса.
Откровенно говоря, удивлен, где это встретилось в ассемблерной вставке. Обычно и в ассемблере такая метка не так часто встречается.

Поскольку ассемблерные вставки, вообще говоря, не стандартизированы, тут каждый компилятор может использовать свой ассемблер, так что лучше читать документацию + учебник того ассемблера, который используется компилятором.

Но встречный вопрос - для чего? Чего именно вы хотите добиться, для чего использовать ассемблер?

Грубо говоря, оптимизировать ассемблерными вставками код, генерируемый современными компиляторами с их оптимизаторами, вы сможете вряд ли, а вот ухудшить его - запросто. Какое-то особо хитрое взаимодействие с системой, едва ли не на уровне железа? Для прикладных программ это имело смысл разве что во времена DOS. Конечно, есть такие специфические области, где ассемблер - рабочий инструмент, но судя по вопросу - это не тот случай...

Comment: Ну, если он вас устраивает - пометьте его как принятый (птичкой)